# Rails How display with two database association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, associations, parameters

I m learning rails since a month. I m making a website for learning more and more. But since 1 week I'm blocked... I try lot of thing, searching on google. But nothing work :(

So I have 4 database :
1) camping (like post)
2) Region (catégory)
3) Departement (state)
3) Ville (city)

I wanna display Camping (post) for specific Region or/and Departement or/and ville.My params can be ID or :slug.

So when user go on exemple.com/regions/1 i want to show departement list for the current region and camping for all this region.

After clicking on one departement exemple.com/nameofregion/nameofdepartement i want to show all city for this departement and all campings for current departement.

For the moment i m working to showing specific departement for the current region. i think region_id was the solution but i m lost... and nothing work ! 
So if you can help me ? Tanks :)

(Ps i m french)

```
Table DEPARTEMENTS
CREATE TABLE "departements" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "description" text, "nomdep" varchar, "departement_id" integer, "slug" varchar, "region_id" integer, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)

TABLE REGIONS
CREATE TABLE "regions" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "descriptionregion" text, "nomderegion" text, "slug" text, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)
```

Routes.rb

```
get 'departements' => 'departements#index'
get 'regions' => 'regions#index'
get 'regions/:region_id' => 'regions#detail'
```

Region.rb

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :departements
  has_many :villes
  has_many :campings
end
```

Departement.rb

```
class Departement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
end
```

Regions_controller

```
class RegionsController < ApplicationController
def index
@regions = Region.all
end

def detail
#@departementids = Departement.all
#@departementids = Departement.find_by_region_id(13)
@departements = Departement.includes(:region)
end
end
```

Detail.html.erb

```
<% @departements.each do |departement| %>
<p><%= departement.region.id %></p>
<% end %>

// And all the tests...//
<%# for departement in @departementids %>
<p><%#= departement.description %></p>
<%#end%>

<%# @departement_ids.each do |region| %>
<li><%#= region.nom %></li>
<%# end %>

<%#@departement_ids.each do |departement| %>
<%#= departement.region_id %>
<%# end %>


<%# @departementsdet.each do |nomdep, regions_id| %>
<%#= @departementsdet.description %>
<%#end%>


<%#@departementsdet.each do |departement| %>
<%#= @departement.description %>
<%# end %>
```

So whats wrong ?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks you're a bit confused with Active Record Associations.

First of a all, let's start with your database.  Departments should have an id and a region_id to have a successful `:belongs_to region`

The way you declared your relations is fine, but remember rails puts convention over configuration. So, having a department_id in your departments table is not necessary.

Your routes.rb also seems fine, at least for what you're trying to do.

So, in our region_controller.rb you can simply go to your detail method (or whatever method you have for a specific view) and whenever you instantiate an object to display in your view, you can:

`@region = Region.find(:id)
 @region.departements`

To access a value from the association.

So, in your view you can:

`<℅ @region.departments.each do |department| %>`

You don't have to explicitly declare a relation in the controller since it's already declared in your models.

You can see your relations 'on the go' using Rails Console.

Simply. `rails console` on your terminal/cmd and then you can for example:

```
region = Region.first
region.departements
```

And this should display all departments associated with that region_id belonging to the Region object's id.

**UPDATE**

Okey, let us check some things that you need in order to use the awesome functionality of rails.

Your models must be singular (ex: region.rb, department.rb)

Your controllers also singular with _controller appended (region_controller.rb, department_controller.rb)

So, if you are sure this is all set remember that in your detail method inside your region_controller.rb you should have something like this:

```
@region = Region.find(params[:id])
```

Then, in your view you can fetch the associated data by calling the plural of department, like this

```
<% @region.departaments.each do |department| %>
<℅= department.name %>
<%= department.any_value ℅>
```

Beware of typos! Specially between singulars and plurals.

Also, make sure your database actually have the values you're calling for

If in doubt, simply check your migrations and make sure to run them with:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Let me know if you manage to get it working!

Bonne chance!
A bientôt!

Comment: @nicolaswecandoit check updated answer. I added a new answer by mistake.